# Selecting dynamically created elements with jquery

Tags: jquery, dynamic, attributes, element

[image]

I am implementing a paging navbar on a table. Yes I know jquery data-tables do all the work for you very neatly but the powers that be do not want to use "widgets"
I am dynamically creating buttons for pages of 10 results. I want to disable the button whose page is currently displayed. I create the buttons like this...

```
<td>
        @{int pages = Model;
            int num = 0;
            while (num < pages)
            {
                num++;
                <input type="button" onclick="fnPage_click(@(num));" style="background-color:transparent; color:deepskyblue" value=@(num) id="btn" + @(num) />
            }
        }
</td>
```

I attempt to select it in javascript like this...

```
$('btn' + multiplyer).attr("disabled", true);
```

which is interpreted by jquery as ...

[image]

Which looks like the correct selector $('btn1').disabled, but it looks like that value remains false regardless of my setting. Not sure if I'm looking at the right disable attribute found it a couple places.
[image]
[image]
Regardless the button is not disabled.

Has anyone else found a reliable way of identifying and selecting dynamically generated elements in jquery?

Comment: You need `#` to select by ID, `$('#btn' + multiplyer)`

Comment: Thanks Paul, that did it. Jquery nube mistake